# Parsing HTML in DB2 Strings

Tags: sql, db2

I have rich text, HTML coming in as CLOBs in one of my tables from Maximo. I need to strip the HTML tags and get cleansed data from it, and apparently there's nothing I could find on it which could help me out. My DB2 doesn't have REGEX so I can't use that.

Comment: [No](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1227152)

Comment: DB2 does have regular expression functions - check out Db2 11.1